# ClienteBase.h:33:7: note: candidate expects 2 argument, 0 provided

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I'm new at C++ programming and I'm trying to instantiate a constructor in a derived class. My base class is ClienteBase:

```
class ClienteBase: public ClienteComprar{
    protected:
        string nome;
        double saldo;
    public:
        ClienteBase(string n, double s);
        int comprarProduto();
};
```

and the constructor from my class ClienteFisico is:

```
ClienteFisico::ClienteFisico(string n, double s, string c){
    ClienteBase(n, s);
    cpf = c;
}
```

I don't see what is the problem, but when I compile it gives me an error, saying that ClienteBase needs two arguments and have zero, but the n and s are arguments, right?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably meant to write a member inititializer list: `ClienteFisico::ClienteFisico(string n, double s, string c) :
    ClienteBase(n, s) { // ...`

Comment: The compiler complains about the initialisation. `ClienteBase(n, s);` in the constructor body doesn't initialise the base class — it creates a completely different but unnamed object and immediately discards it.

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization needs to be done in the initializer list.

```
Foo::Foo(... agrs ...) : ... initializer list ...
                       ^ // Start of initializer list
{ // Start of constructor body
}
```

Therefore your should be doing

```
ClienteFisico::ClienteFisico(string n, double s, string c) :
    ClienteBase(n, s), // Now calling parent constructor
    cpf(c) // This isn't required to be here but is preferred over the body
{
}
```